# rsync from server to local home folder while keeping file ownership

Tags: rsync

Backing up a website to my home folder while trying to keep file ownership.

```
rsync -az  user@server.com:/www/site ~/backup
```

If I understand, the -a option is the same as -rlptgoD in which -o and -g maintain owner and group. Right?

files to be backed up are all set as user:user, is not an admin (shared host).

When I run the command the files on my local machine all are changed to be in my local user:group.

The basic question is how do I maintain the original ownership of the files?
Or am I going about this the wrong way? And should be taring the files then transferring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot maintain ownership and group of a file unless you either own the files already or you are root. (This fits in with the principle that you cannot "give away" files.) You can use the `--fake-super` flag to record the ownership and group in extended attributes so that if you restore with sufficient permissions you can restore those previously saved values.

```
# Backup
rsync -az --fake-super user@server.com:/www/site ~/backup

# Restore
rsync -az --fake-super ~/backup root@server.com:/www/site
```

If you cannot log in as root on the remote system but you have (say) the ability to run `sudo` without it prompting for a password, you can mangle the command line like this:

```
# Restore via sudo
rsync -az --fake-super --rsync-path='sudo rsync' ~/backup root@server.com:/www/site
```

The `--fake-super` flag also sidesteps problems with the user and group names not existing on the target system (although there is the `--numeric-ids` option if you decide not to use `--fake-super`). Just be aware that it look a bit strange on the target system until you realise that it really is working in the background. Symlinks, for example, also stop being symlinks while backed-up.

A potential issue is that `rsync` prefers to copy owner and group information by name rather than UID/GID. This can cause problems if the names don't exist on the target system. Fortunately the `--numeric-ids` flag allows you to tell `rsync` to copy by UID/GID instead of by name.

Comment: Ahh, I was trying the --fake-super option and didn't get that it would just "hide" the info until the files were sent back up! Great info/answer. Thanks

Comment: @ecotechie yes, the `--fake-super` is a bit weird on the destination system. I've updated my answer a little with that regard.